# DataTables TableTools images not working with ThemeRoller

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I have `tabletools` up and running with `datatables` and it works great. The only problem I am having is icons for the `tabletools` buttons. When they are outside the header div using `"sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lf>rt<"F"ip>'` the icons show up just fine, when I put the `tabletools` inside the header, the icons dont show up `"sDom": '<"H"lTf>rt<"F"ip>'`

The image illustrates both combined `"sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lTf>rt<"F"ip>'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when i use  "bJQueryUI": true, i may think there is a problem with the jqueryUI if there is not a problem you can use collection instead for example:

```
"oTableTools": { "aButtons": [{"sExtends":    "collection","sButtonText": "Save", "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]},]
```

It will show the icons in a list