# Jquery datatable - Excel export is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have implement the excel export in datatable. Have included the the tabletool reference and SWF put into my local workspace.

```
var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
       "aaData": newarray,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bDeferRender": true,
       "bFilter": false,
       "bRetrieve": true,
       "bPaginate": true,
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sPaginationType": "two_button",
       "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
       "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
             "aButtons": [ "xls" ]
        },
       "bSort": true,
```

Its just displaying the Export option in table header, but there is no action , nothing happening.Is there any step i need to do ? if i'm keeping blank without mention oTableTools, print option is working fine , so my environment is working good.

Please advise which step i have not done ?

Thanks

Comment: Any body have idea about this issue ?

Comment: I am not sure whats happening with your code, but this might help you http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html

Comment: Maybe also try the alternative initialization setup method: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/alt_init.html

Comment: Maybe try using a root-relative url instead, like "/tools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"...?

Comment: Please tell me how to use root-relative ?

Comment: Start the sSwfPath value with a backslash (which represents the root directory of your site) followed by the path from your root to the swf file.

Comment: Or use the full path, like `http://localhost/webfolder/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf`

Comment: @Stefan , Able to download now...While moving to production, how to specify the full path ? and its downloading as csv format...I'm need excel all the data in excel sheet.How to download file as xls file ?

Comment: Try this url: `http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf`  It might solve the Excel issue as well.

Comment: I tried this url , its not not working and copy_csv_x‌​ls_pdf.swf with local url eventhough its downloading csv only. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you add the script at "/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"?

Comment: Yes , i have added both js TableTools.js,ZeroClipboard.js

Comment: I found out that this is not a bug - it simply hasn't been implemented yet! http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4043/export-to-excel-wrong-extention-.csv./p1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I eventually discovered that the reason why Export to Excel also creates a .csv file (which can be read by Excel) is because it is meant to do so.  This is not a bug, it simply hasn't been implemented yet - see the discussion here: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4043/export-to-excel-wrong-extention-.csv./p1

The other issue is that the sSwfPath is important to specify correctly. It seems to work best when the full server path is used instead of a relative url?  An alternative to using a local file is to use `http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_x‌​ls_pdf.swf`. UPDATE: This link no longer exists and I have not been able to find a replacement link yet.

Remove Excel button:

```
'oTableTools' : {
    'aButtons': ['copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'print']
};
```

Button options:

http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/button_options

Button Icons and jQuery UI: [DataTables TableTools images not working with ThemeRoller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8751126/888177)

Possible ways to create icons/positions for buttons, maybe:

1. Specify a CSS background-image and position for a button
2. Use `<img src='..>` inside the sButtonText property of a button
3. Use jQuery to change the `html('<img ..>')` of a button

Comment: Cool , Thanks for your help.I'll accept your answer...Just one more help , how to replace excel icon instead of button and button is displaying on left side , but it suppose to b right side will be looks good.

Comment: @user2444474 I am not 100% sure what you mean, but I have added some info to my answer which might help you.

Comment: The Link to the swf file is broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
Required Files
1)datatable/media/css/demo_table_jui.css
2)datatable/media/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css
3)datatable/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css
4)datatable/media/js/1.9/jquery.dataTables.js
5)datatable/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js
6)datatable/media/js/TableTools.js 

First use the `jquery datable js 1.9` (please check the below link where you can download this js)
and second use the code like below to view datatable

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
            {
                'sExtends':'csv',
                "sFileName": "filetitle.csv",
                'mColumns':[0,1]
            },
            {
                    'sExtends':'pdf',
                    "sFileName": "filetitle.pdf",
                    'mColumns':[0,1] 
            },
        ]
        },
        "sDom": '<"H"Tlfr>tip<"F">',
        "aoColumns":
        [
            { "bSearchable": false },
            null,   // as per requirement
            { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
        ]
    });

please remember main code for export to excel is as below
which is added in the above code

    "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [
        {
        'sExtends':'csv',
        "sFileName": "subscribers.csv",
        'mColumns':[0,1]
        },
        {
        'sExtends':'pdf',
        "sFileName": "subscribers.pdf",
        'mColumns':[0,1] 
        },
    ]
    },
    "sDom": '<"H"Tlfr>tip<"F">',

and then download the "media" folder from this link and paste into the folder where you datagrid show

[Please check here](http://codeace.in/download/)


please check screenshot [here][2] as per required file from `media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` is required to export functionality.

`[NOTE : please extract and paste the "media" folder in the accurate path on which page your datatable is display .]`


  [1]: http://codeace.in/download/1.9.zip
  [2]: http://codeace.in/download/_2014-04-11%2013-57-20.png
```

Comment: Reuired files 
1)datatable/media/css/demo_table_jui.css
2)datatable/media/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css
3)datatable/media/css/TableTools_JUI.css
4)datatable/media/js/1.9/jquery.dataTables.js
5)datatable/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js
6)datatable/media/js/TableTools.js